# HTML, PHP  построение и обработка форм

Tags: html, php, форма

Собственно у меня есть массив с названиями файлов, я вывожу его в следующем виде

```
<b>Список файлов:</b><br><br>

<form method="post" action="">

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tbody><tr><td width="80%">
_samoe_nujnoe_o_prirodnyih_vodah_-_chast_1
</td><td width="15%"><center>
<input id="refresh" name="refresh" value="Обработать" type="submit"></center>
</td></tr></tbody></table>

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tbody><tr><td width="80%">
_samoe_nujnoe_o_prirodnyih_vodah_-_chast_2
</td><td width="15%"><center>
<input id="refresh" name="refresh" value="Обработать" type="submit"></center>
</td></tr></tbody></table>

-----------------------------------------

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tbody><tr><td width="80%">
_samoe_nujnoe_o_prirodnyih_vodah_-_chast_N
</td><td width="15%"><center>
<input id="refresh" name="refresh" value="Обработать" type="submit"></center>
</td></tr></tbody></table>

</form>
```

внешний вид всего етого примерно такой:
http://xatak.ru/aaaaa.JPG

вопрос как правильно прописать атрибуты кнопок, что при нажатии на одну из них передавалась переменная например FileName и она имела значение из первого столбца таблицы... название файла в первую колонку выводится переменной $file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял...

```
<form method="post" action="">

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="80%">
<span>имя файла</span>
<input type='hidden' name='filename' value='имя файла'>
</td>
<td width="15%">
<input id="refresh" name="refresh" value="Обработать" type="submit">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо!, то что надо!

Comment: В этом варианте всегда будет передаваться последнее имя файла, а не то, чья кнопка была нажата..

Comment: Можно каждую таблицу обернуть в форму, тогда будет то, что надо.

Answer (score 1):

Вывод списка:

```
<?php
$files = [
    "file1",
    "file2",
    "file3"
];
?>
<b>Список файлов:</b><br><br>
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <?php foreach($files as $key=>$file): ?>
    <table width="100%" border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td width="80%"><?=$file;?></td>
        <td width="15%">
            <center>
            <input type="hidden" name="file[]" value="<?=$file;?>" />
            <input name="refresh[<?=$key;?>]" value="Refresh" type="submit">
            </center>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
?>
```

Обработка (пример):

```
<?php 
$keys = array_keys($_POST['refresh']);
$key = array_pop($keys);
echo $_POST['file'][$key];
?>
```